Saving objects as part of a for-loop but passing object name into loop as a string
I spent the weekend enjoying my leisure time while my computer assiduously ran a series of 31 bayesian models in R (using the brms package). I assigned each of these model objects a name. When I returned this morning I had 31 model objects in my workspace. Good job computer! Sadly, what I did not do on Friday afternoon was write code to save each of these model objects. It will take a LONG time to rerun the models and a fair bit of code to save each of them. So I was wondering if it was possible to save the model objects by passing their name through a for-loop. Simple example included below
# Two models
mod1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
mod2 <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

Now what I want to do for my example is grab the object names in the workspace as a list of names, stored as strings, via ls(). However for the purposes of this simple example I will just store the two model object names as a list manually
objNames <- c("mod1", "mod2")

Now for the for-loop passing the names of the objects as strings into the save() function...
for(i in 1:length(objNames)) {
save(objNames[i],
     file = paste0(objNames[i], ".RData"))
}

....which obviously does not work because I don't know anything about evaluation...and throws the error...
Error in save(objNames[i], file = paste0(objNames[i], ".RData")) : 
  object ‘objNames[i]’ not found 

Any help much appreciated

Use the list argument for strings (e.g. for(i in objNames) {save(list = i, file = paste0(i, ".RData"))}.  Do you really want to save each model individually?  save() can save an arbitrary number of objects but consider gathering your models into a list and saving that.

You mean a list of objects rather than a list of names? Yes that is what I should have done on Friday afternoon and I could easily do it now; I was just curious how to do it. Thank you. I see one could also using indexing syntax in the for-loop for(i in 1:objNames[i]) {save(list = objNames[i], file = paste0(objNames[i], ".RData"))} 

If your models are assigned mod1, mod2,  ... mod31 in the global environment then try model_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^mod\\d+")); save(model_list, file = "model_list.Rdata").

Didn't realise you could put regex into ls(). This solution is even neater. Thank you again! If you put these into an answer I will of course accept.

You can just use save.image here to save everything in your environment (if mod1, mod2, ...) are all that's in there.
save.image(file = "Bayes_mods_31.RData")

Or to specify only the objects that match a pattern:
save(list=ls(pattern = "^mod\\d+"), file = "Bayes_mods_list.RData")

Or if you  want the individual models in separate files, use
invisible(lapply(ls(pattern = "^mod\\d+"), \(mod) save(list=mod, file = paste0(mod, ".RData"))))

Then load them back into R using load:
rm(list=ls())
load("Bayes_mods_31.RData")
ls()
# [1] "mod1" "mod2"

rm(list=ls())
load("Bayes_mods_list.RData")
ls()
# [1] "mod1" "mod2"

# Load one file
rm(list=ls())
load(file="mod1.RData") # Heed warning in help page
ls()
# [1] "mod1"

# Load all "*.RData" fles in the specified directory
rm(list=ls())
invisible(lapply(list.files("F:/", pattern = "mod\\d+\\.RData"), load, .GlobalEnv))
ls()
# [1] "mod1" "mod2"

